# Read text from file in classic ASP using Javascript

Tags: javascript, iis, asp-classic

I'm using classic ASP, and am trying to print the contents of a specific text file to the screen. I know how to do this in VBScript through ASP, but how can one do this in Javascript through ASP?

Comment: It might help if you could post your working VBS example

Comment: You mean server side JS, or client side? Those are totally different things.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using plain JavaScript you can do something like the following.  Just remember to replace the first parameter of the get function will the actual file path including the file extension name(example: myfilename.txt). You must also make sure that the file you are trying to open is from the same domain. Here is a link to an example of how it works (http://bytewarestudios.com/launchjs/get). I removed the get function from a JavaScript library I wrote so you wouldn't have to load the whole library.

HTML:

```
  <div id="results"></div>
```

JavaScript(Place this code in a script tag right before the closing body tag):

```
   //call the get function
   get(pathToTextFile,function(data){

         //display the file contents to the screen.
         document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = data;


    });



function get(url,fn){//begin ajax function

    var contentType;

    //variable to hold the xmlhttp object
    var xmlhttp = null;

    //if a contentType is not passed in
    if(typeof arguments[1] === "function"){//begin if then else

        //set it to default of text/html
        contentType = "text/html"; 

    }//end if then
    else{

        //set the contentType to the argument passed in
        contentType = arguments[1];

    }//end if then else



  //if the browser contains the object
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari

            //create a new XMLHttpRequest object
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5

            //create a new ActiveXObject
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

  }//end if then else

        //add the event listenter
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){       

  //if the status of the request is good 
  if (xmlhttp.readyState===4 && xmlhttp.status===200){//begin if then

    //get the response text and store it in the data variable
    var data = xmlhttp.responseText;    

    //call the ajaxDone callback function
    ajaxDone(data,fn);

    }//end if then 



};//end function

  function ajaxDone(data,fn){//begin function

    //call the anonymous function passing the data returned from the xmlhttp request
    fn(data);    



}//end function
```

Comment: I think the OP meant using server side JS rather than VBS.

Comment: @John that's a 50/50 chance, it's really not clear from the question itself.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I think the way he talks about "VBS through ASP", then "JS through ASP" implies that it's server side, but I agree that it's ambiguous.

Comment: @John well, asked OP directly, let's see if I get an answer.

Comment: I only had a solution that was client side. @John you could be right but who knows for sure like you and Shadow Wizard have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just a case of translating your VBS into JS, it's not that difficult as long as you have a basic understanding of both.

**VBScript example**

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" %>
<%
dim fso, txt, content
set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FilesystemObject")
set txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\Pathto\textfile.txt")
content = txt.ReadAll
Response.Write content
%>
```

**JScript example**

```
<%@ LANGUAGE="JSCRIPT" %>
<%    
var fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
var txt = fso.OpenTextFile("C:\\Pathto\\textfile.txt");
var content = txt.ReadAll();
Response.Write(content);
%>
```

Note that you need to escape the backslashes in Windows filepaths if you're using JS